# what's the difference between static event handler and non-static event handler

Tags: c#, .net

Is there big difference between those two?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Semantically there are no differences, however using static event handlers can (if you're not careful) lead to memory leaks. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658248.aspx) for more info.

I've come across this problem myself, trying to use a static event handler to keep an application-wide data source up to date; the event handler was preventing my `BindingSource` components from being disposed, leading to all sorts of weird problems...

Comment: +1 for the warning, @Bradley. Shouldn't you just need to unsubscribe to the event prior to `Dispose()`?

Comment: @dboarman Yeah, that would be essential. For anything that doesn't implement `IDisposable`, you need to be very careful... It's probably good practice to ensure that subscribers to static events -always- implement it. Also make sure your object actually gets disposed! (that one has caught me out before)

Comment: Agreed...static events should be used with attention to detail.

Comment: The memory leak problem is with static events, not static event **handlers**. It not the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Effectively none. All it means is that when the handler is static, there will be no `this` in scope (as with all static methods).